# Use integration by parts in cylindrical coordinates to turn these second derivatives into first derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, quantum-mechanics, cylindrical-coordinates

I have a complex function $\psi(\rho,z)$ in cylindrical coordinates, which has the conditions $\psi=0$ as $z\rightarrow\pm\infty$ and $\rho\rightarrow +\infty$. The quantity $E$ given by the double integral
$$
E = 2\pi\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}\int_{\rho=0}^{\rho=+\infty} \Bigg( \psi^*\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial\rho^2} + \psi^*\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\rho} + \psi^*\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial z^2} \Bigg) \rho \;\textrm{d}\rho\, \textrm{d}z \tag{1}
$$
where $\psi^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $\psi$, and the $2\pi$ appears because I have integrated out the angular coordinate, since $\psi$ is cylindrically-symmetric. (The quantity $E$ expresses the kinetic energy of a quantum mechanical wavefunction).

I would like to simplify this expression so that it contains first derivatives instead of second derivatives.

I know that in one-dimension in a variable $x$, I can use integration by parts to write the following
$$
\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \psi^* \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} \,\textrm{d}x = \Bigg[ \psi^* \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \Bigg]^{+\infty}_{-\infty} - \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x} \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \,\textrm{d}x
$$
and if $\psi=0$ at $\pm\infty$ the first term vanishes to give
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \psi^* \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} \,\textrm{d}x &= - \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x} \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \,\textrm{d}x\\
&= - \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \bigg(\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x}\bigg)^* \bigg(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\bigg) \,\textrm{d}x \\
&= - \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} \Bigg|\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\Bigg|^2\,\textrm{d}x .
\end{align}
$$
Is it possible to use a similar trick to write Eq. (1) in terms of first derivatives? I am struggling with the order of integration and how to apply the integration by parts in 2D here, given that there is an extra factor of $\rho$ from the volume element in cylindrical coordinates.

If someone could take me through it that would be great, thank you!

Comment: The same trick does apply, but now it gives (writing the indefinite integral for simplicity) $$\int \psi^* \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial \rho ^2} \rho dx = \psi^* \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \rho  - \int \frac{\partial(\rho \psi^*)}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \rho} \,d\rho.$$
The derivative further expands to $\frac{\partial(\rho \psi)^*}{\partial x}=\rho \frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial \rho}+\psi^*.$ So that doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, your comment was very helpful. I still have a question though. When you put the limits in to the first term of your first equation ($\rho=0$ to $\rho=\infty$), it's not clear to me that the whole term should disappear. In the simple 1D example I gave in the OP this term definitely disappeared because $\psi=0$ at $\pm\infty$. In the cylindrically-symmetric case, 1) there is an exatr factor of $\rho$, 2) can I assume $\partial\psi/\partial\rho=0$ at $\rho=0$?

Comment: That extra factor of $\rho$ by itself should ensure that the boundary term vanishes at the origin. (That said, the behavior at the origin of $\psi$ can be a bit strange if I remember right.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Okay, yes I think I am convinced of that. Another thing is how to handle integration by parts of the term of the form $$  \int_{\rho=0}^{\rho=+\infty} \psi^* \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial z^2} \, \textrm{d}\rho$$ i.e when carrying out the first integral over $\rho$, but the partial derivative is with respect to $z$?

Comment: You're also integrating with respect to $z$. So just integrate by parts using that integration.